# how to change time to country with php in form mail

Tags: php, forms, email, country

i use this code to display time

```
$in_Body .= 'Time: ' .  gmdate('F j, Y, h:i:s A') . "\n\n";
```

but i want display time by country like egypt

complete code

```
<?php
$webmaster_mail = 'sales@elfnoon.com';
$redirect_page = 'elfnoon.com/';
$message_subject = 'رسالة من زائر لموقعك';
$in_Body ='';
foreach($_POST as $in_k=>$in_v) {
  $in_Body .="$in_k = $in_v\n\n";
}
$in_Body .= 'IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n\n";
$in_Body .= 'Browser: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";
$in_Body .= 'Time: ' .  gmdate('F j, Y, h:i:s A') . "\n\n";
mail(trim($webmaster_mail), "$message_subject ", "$in_Body","From: " . trim($webmaster_mail));
header("Location: $redirect_page");
?>
```

any idea???

Comment: this is time i want show it

(UTC+02:00) Cairo

Comment: any other one have the idea????

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use Egyptian time, take a look at [**date_default_timezone_set**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) and [the list of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

*gmdate* returns a time based on the GMT timezone. Egypt is UTC + 2.

Comment: i see is Africa/Cairo but i dont how to make it with my file :(

Comment: date_default_timezone_set sets a default timezone for all date and time functions used after it is called. 

So, the following would be place at the top of your file:   

    date_default_timezone_set('Africa/Cairo');

Answer (score 0):

Set timezone in your code:-

```
 ini_set('date.timezon','Europe/Brussels');
```

Or try this

```
<?php

ini_set('date.timezon','Europe/Brussels');
$webmaster_mail = 'sales@elfnoon.com';
$redirect_page = 'elfnoon.com/';
$message_subject = '????? ?? ???? ??????';
$in_Body ='';
foreach($_POST as $in_k=>$in_v) {
  $in_Body .="$in_k = $in_v\n\n";
}
$in_Body .= 'IP: ' . $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] . "\n\n";
$in_Body .= 'Browser: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";
$in_Body .= 'Time: ' .  gmdate('F j, Y, h:i:s A') . "\n\n";
mail(trim($webmaster_mail), "$message_subject ", "$in_Body","From: " . trim($webmaster_mail));
header("Location: $redirect_page");
?>
```

Comment: set time zone according to you ini_set('date.timezon','Europe/Brussels');